# How to get each datapoint into a separate series in an Excel 3D bubble chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When creating a 3D bubble chart (or any other X Y scatter) in Excel, is there any **simple** way to tell Excel that every data point should be in a new series?

When I simply mark the data area and open the “Insert Chart” dialog, Excel will recommend me a chart, where all data points are in the same series.

[image: Insert chart dialog and the dummy data I used for the charts in this questions]

The automatically created chart - how it should not look like

[image: The automatically created chart - how it should not look like]

The benefit of having each data point in a separate series would be to show the series names in the legend.

How it should look like: A new series for each data point

[image: How it should look like: A new series for each data point]

I understand that I could simply right click the chart, click “Select data” and add the series manually, but with larger data sets, this takes time. And of course, it could be achieved using VBA. But I find it hard to believe, that there is no simple and efficient solution for that.

As a workaround, I tried the “Vary colors by point” option in “Format Data Series”. Then I even get all the data points in the legend. However, Excel names them by their x-value.

Vary colors by point

[image: Vary colors by point]

Any solution for this problem (or any workaround) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you don't mind outsourcing.. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2017-excel-create-bubble-chart.html should be helpful.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Thank you very much! I found that site on my web research before I posted the question, too. It’s for sure a useful tool, I am just surprised that there is no simple, native way to do that in Excel without add ins.